# RabbitMQ losing Events during SpringBoot Transactions

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have updated rabbitMQ to 3.10.0 whit multiple nodes. Since the Update some Events (~1 in 5.000 Events) are disapearing invisible for the SpringBoot Application that publishes those messages. The Log of rabbitMQ shows the following error message

```
2023-03-10 07:36:27.169246+01:00 [error] <0.16429.2271> Error on AMQP connection <0.16429.2271> (10.16.67.140:53607 -> 10.16.65.217:5671 - my-application-name-9.99.9#22.publisher, vhost: 'prod', user: 'sys_user', state: running), channel 4:
2023-03-10 07:36:27.169246+01:00 [error] <0.16429.2271>  operation basic.publish caused a connection exception channel_error: "unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit'"
2023-03-10 07:36:27.173499+01:00 [info] <0.16429.2271> closing AMQP connection <0.16429.2271> (10.16.67.140:53607 -> 10.16.65.217:5671 - my-application-name-2.63.1#22.publisher, vhost: 'prod', user: 'sys_user')
2023-03-10 07:36:27.180047+01:00 [info] <0.6107.2408> accepting AMQP connection <0.6107.2408> (10.16.67.140:21298 -> 10.16.65.217:5671)
2023-03-10 07:36:27.181673+01:00 [info] <0.6107.2408> connection <0.6107.2408> (10.16.67.140:21298 -> 10.16.65.217:5671) has a client-provided name: my-application-name-2.63.1#23.publisher
2023-03-10 07:36:27.184094+01:00 [info] <0.6107.2408> connection <0.6107.2408> (10.16.67.140:21298 -> 10.16.65.217:5671 - my-application-name-9.99.9#23.publisher): user 'sys_user' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'prod'
```

RabbiMQ gets an error 'during commit' not sending this error to the Spring-Boot-Application not causing a rollback of the Spring Application Transaction. Somehow it is only one specific Spring-Boot Application that has those errors. ~50 other Applications are running smothly.

Spring-Boot 2.7.7 , Spring Cloud 2021.0.5 , Messages are sent via Spring-Cloud-Stream

If anyone has an idea/any approach where to start looking i would be thankfull.

Restarts of RabbitMQ/the application, updating the Artefact, changing the Primary RabbitMQ Node that gets used for publishing has not changed anything. Since it only occurs a few times per thousands of events i have absolutly no idea what to do.

**EDIT**
Reducing the number of RabbitMQ Nodes sigificantly reduces the number of errors.

**EDIT EDIT** I found a "solution" --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/76216786/10254476

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. During a power outage multiple servers died. Including all servers that ran all RabbitMQ instances. This resulted in the RabbitMQ Culster beeing down. After this outage no more error messages regarding "tx.commit" have been found in RabbitMQ.

Previous restarts that have been tried where always in sequential order. The Culster was always kept alive since one rabbitMQ instance was always available. This seems to have kept the bug alive.

If anyone reading this has similar issues I would suggest a "real restart" in which all RabbitMQ Instances are down for a sort time.